# Seleccionar el hijo del pariente de un div seleccionado

Tags: javascript, html

estoy tratando de hacer una pestaña desplegable de una tabla de divs y quisiera cambiarle el valor de un div, específicamente el hijo de un padre que conozco su id, algo así:

```
<div id="pariente">
  <div id="hijo">Inactivo</div>
</div>
<div id="selector-1">Selector</div>

function toggle_visibility(id) { 
        var e = document.getElementById(id); 
        e.style.display = ((e.style.display!='none') ? 'none' : 'block'); 
}
```

Un dato adicional es, que el id=Pariente es un módulo de varios repetidos, y hay más selector-1. Necesito qué al hacer click en el selector en otro div poder accesar al div=Hijo y modificarle el "Inactivo" por "Activo". Muchas gracias, espero con ansias sus respuestas. Saludos

Comment: Es decir, ¿das click en el selector y accedes al elemento hijo del pariente verdad?

Comment: Exacto! Ya tengo habilitado el toggle para mostrar y ocultar selector-1 (la info adentro) pero necesito obtener el pariente > hijo anterior a el. Por qué no es el único "Pariente" que hay. `
function toggle_visibility(id) {
 var e = document.getElementById(id);
 e.style.display = ((e.style.display!='none') ? 'none' : 'block');
}` Tengo esto para hacer el toggle.

Comment: La nueva información deberías de añadirla en la pregunta. Recuerda que si usas Cntrl+M puedes formatear tu ejercicio dentro de la misma.

Answer (score 2):

No deberías tener varios `id=pariente` pero si no puedes diferenciar ese div de otros se puede seleccionar el elemento anterior y luego su hijo, algo así:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("selector-1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild.innerHTML = "activo";
  });
};
```

```css
#selector-1 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#selector-1:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="pariente">
  <div id="hijo">inactivo</div>
</div>
<div id="selector-1">selector</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podría ser `document.querySelector("pariente").children[0].innerHTML = "Inactivo"#`

Claro obviamente con la programación de el valor intercambiable para poder poner activo e Inactivo